# Setting up a Samba share with guest access

Tags: samba

I am trying to setup guest access to a samba share but am getting nowhere. I have had to purge samba multiple times.
Here is my smb.conf:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
    dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
    max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
    syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
    server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

    obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
    unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
    pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
    map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
    usershare allow guests = yes
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    security = user
;   encrypt passwords = yes
    guest ok = yes
;   guest account = nobody

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
;   guest ok = no
;   read only = yes
    create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
;   browseable = yes
;   read only = yes
;   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[Downloads]
    path = /media/me/3TB/Downloads
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! What do you mean by "I am going nowhere"? What exactly goes wrong? Is there an error message, or other unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Currently can see the share from a windows 7 machine and an Openelec device but they are unable to access it. Do not have the permissions to do so.

Comment: hello did you try to add this section to the smb.conf              
[share] guest ok = yes then test the configuration `sudo testparm -v`

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your `smb.conf` for the "Downloads" share access :

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0

#... (other global settings)

[Downloads]
   path = /media/me/3TB/Downloads
   writeable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
```

After making these changes, save the `smb.conf` file and restart the Samba service using the following command:

```bash
sudo service smbd restart
```

This should allow guest access to the "Downloads" share without requiring a username and password. Also make sure the directory `/media/me/3TB/Downloads` has the appropriate permissions to allow guest access.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to append the following at the end of my default/original `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
# ANONYMOUS Guest Access; PLEASE COMMENT OUT WHEN NOT IN USE; Also don't
# forget to enter the command `sudo service smbd restart` after configuration
# changes.
[guest]
        # This share allows anonymous (guest) access
        # without authentication!
        path = /share_samba_guest/
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
```

Add the above piece of code at the end of your configuration, save the configuration file. The path is assigned with `/share_samba_guest/` which you can create with `sudo mkdir /share_samba_guest/ && sudo chmod 777 /share_samba_guest/`. Then you must restart the samba service with `sudo service smbd restart` or `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service` .

Use `ip addr` to get IP address of your host computer. Use this IP address to connect to your LAN share. I am able to connect to this share, read/write, in my Android device using *Mi File Manager*.

Answer (score -1):

Samba on LAN can have guest access. Assuming you're using ubuntu / debian this tutorial should be OK. It was successful for me.

http://www.debuntu.org/samba-how-to-share-files-for-your-lan-without-userpassword/

Comment: I have followed the guide, but it is inaccessible from windows. The shared folder is located on an NTFS formatted drive, is this an issue?

Comment: This guide is 8 years old and way out of date

Comment: @thrau care to provide an update guide? I'm trying to configure a share from nemo/nautilus but keeps asking for password even though guest access is set.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem of viewing the network folder but having no access. I followed [this](https://techjourney.net/cannot-connect-to-cifs-smb-samba-network-shares-shared-folders-in-windows-10/) guide to fix it.