# Samba guest account share with r/w access, clients are Macs

Tags: samba, security

I want to make a directory of files on my server available to anyone on the LAN.  I want them to have read/write access.

Googling about this, you basically end up here:

https://www.debuntu.org/samba-how-to-share-files-for-your-lan-without-userpassword/

For example it's linked to from this askubuntu question: [Setting up a Samba share with guest access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489959/setting-up-a-samba-share-with-guest-access)

It suggests changing "security = share" to "security = user".  But the smb.conf file doesn't have that line.  That link is from 2007, so any information there has to be considered extremely suspect.  Especially when it has anything to do with security.

Anyway, I've got my share set up like this:

```
[public]                        
   comment = Public shared folder
   path = /media/ZhongNanHai                                    
   browseable = yes                                             
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
```

Now I try to connect from my Macintosh.  In Finder I select "Connect to Server...", type in the name of my machine with a "smb://" prefix, and click "Connect".  It offers to log in as a Registered User, but I can select to connect as "Guest" instead.  When I do so, it asks me to select a volume.  "public" is there, but it's greyed out and I can't select it.

What's wrong with my configuration that prevents me accessing this share?